# Check if the pointer is on restore button of a window - autohotkey

Tags: windows-10, automation, autohotkey

I would like to know a piece of code that allows if the mouse pointer is over the restore "❐" button.

I would like pressing and sliding the restore button to the side to split the current window, just like the "Win + ←/→" shortcut. It is a function that I saw in Preme for Windows and I would like only that functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We're not a code-writing service. What have you tried already?

Comment: This feels very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What *precisely* are you trying to achieve? [Not what you think you need to do to achieve it.]

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenient. I look for a piece of code that, for example, I position the pointer on the restore button that all windows have and press "F4", then a MsgBox appears that recognizes that the pointer is over the restore button. Otherwise, the MsgBox is not launched. That's the problem, I haven't found any solution in the forums, maybe you know a hint on how to do it or how to find it? Thanks

Comment: There's a bunch of material on the AHK forums. E.g. you can learn that the Windows GUI buttons have fixed length and you can do things based on that. You should do more accurate research. This question isn't any specific still and will be closed.

Comment: For whar purpose do you need it?

Comment: I would like pressing and sliding the restore button to the side to split the current window, just like the "Win + ←/→" shortcut. It is a function that I saw in Preme for Windows and I would like only that functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this MouseGestures script](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=57037#p242294):

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force


~LButton::      ; gesture hotkey
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseGetPos, mX, mY, WindowUnderMouse
WinGetPos, wX, wY, wW, wH, ahk_id %WindowUnderMouse%
If (mY > wY and mY < wY+50 and (mX > wX + (wW-150) and mX < wX+wW)) ; mouse is over one of the buttons minimize,restore or close
{
    KeyWait, %A_ThisHotkey%, T0.1   ;to identify if hotkey was pressed or held...
    If ErrorLevel{
        ;hotkey is being held down so treat it as a gesture...
        GetMouseGesture(True)
        While GetKeyState(LTrim(A_ThisHotkey,"~"), "P"){
            ToolTip % MG := GetMouseGesture()
            Sleep 150
        }
        IsFunc(MG) ? %MG%() : ""    ;example allows creation of gestures by defining functions that comprise U,D,R,L as function name,with no upper limit on the extent of the gesture,i.e UDUDUDUDL for ex.
        ToolTip
        GetMouseGesture(True)
    }Else
        Send  {%A_ThisHotkey%}  ;if ordinary press, just let the press,passthrough...
}
Return

; gesture Left
L(){
    SendInput, #{Left}
}

; gesture Right
R(){
    SendInput, #{Right}
}

GetMouseGesture(reset := false){
    Static
    mousegetpos,xpos2, ypos2
    dx:=xpos2-xpos1,dy:=ypos1-ypos2
    ,( abs(dy) >= abs(dx) ? (dy > 0 ? (track:="u") : (track:="d")) : (dx > 0 ? (track:="r") : (track:="l")) )   ;track is up or down, left or right
    ,abs(dy)<4 and abs(dx)<4 ? (track := "") : ""   ;not tracking at all if no significant change in x or y
    ,xpos1:=xpos2,ypos1:=ypos2
    ,track<>SubStr(gesture, 0, 1) ? (gesture := gesture . track) : ""   ;ignore track if not changing since previous track
    ,gesture := reset ? "" : gesture
    Return gesture
}
```